# How to add a JMPS modul on module-path for mvn test?

Tags: maven, java-platform-module-system

How to add different *JPMS* modules on the *module-path* for different runs of *mvn test*?

The added module shall be there only for test purposes, without changing the *pom.xml* of the project.

My overall tasks is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080261/how-to-put-a-service-provider-java-spi-module-on-module-path-for-mvn-test) in more detail.

Comment: Different runs of tests with different modules? The is usually the intention to run for exactly one unit testing of a particular part in your software.. or are you trying to run the same tests with different "implementations" ?

Comment: Yes, khmarbaise, I would like to test my Java Service API (SPI) client project against one or more Service Providers, which are not part of the tested project, but kind of test resource.